# Нахождения файла и выполнения команды

Tags: python, файлы

Здравствуйте мне нужно просматривать папку через Python код и при обнаружении нового файла выполнить команду на тот же найденный файл но имя не известно как это сделать и возможно ли?

Comment: а как вы узнаете что это тот самый файл, на который нужно выполнить команду ?

Comment: ну просто любой файл.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно так сделать:

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
mypath = 'D:\\'
for f in listdir(mypath):
    if isfile(join(mypath, f)):
        print(f) # тут ваши действия
```

Comment: Спасибо Большое это помогло в моей проблеме!